# Applications of diophantine approximation in counting (combinatorics).

Tags: combinatorics, big-list, diophantine-approximation

In what situations, if any, do Diophantine approximations of numbers come up when attempting to count something? In other words, what are some combinatorics applications of Diophantine approximations that arise from "natural problems"/easy-to-explain problems?